# Join csv files and sort to look like result from SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

I have mysql database, and i run sql query on that database with joins and where clause, lets say query will look like

```
SELECT a.value1,
       a.value2,
       b.value3,
       c.value4
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.some_value=b.some_value
LEFT JOIN table3 c ON a.some_value=c.some_value
WHERE a.some_value = 'some_text';
```

and i run query 1000times to get average time needed for this query on database with 4.5milions records.

But, i need help if it is possible
because i don't have idea is it possible and if it is possible, how to do, and where to start for next steps.

That steps are: i want to export in CSV files 
table1, table2 and table3 (and that is ok, i know to export tables in csv file), after that, in PHP i want to load each csv file, and to get almost exact result as this SQL query give.
Also i want to run this query 1.000 times and to get average time. I want to do these to make comparison between running query on tables and sorting from csv files.

Comment: And what exactly do you want us to do, besides suggest that you're almost certainly going to be waiting a long time even to execute this once from csv files, let alone 1000 times, and the coding to do so is going to take hours/days rather than minutes..... it can be done, but why do you  want to put yourself through the pain?

Comment: @MarkBaker because i want to make comparison, because i want to learn, but i don't know how is possible and where to start from because i haven't done this kind, and starting point, and what to do will be very helpfull, because after that i want to test this also from python, on mysql it takes about 50sec to execute, i want to know how it's done from php and what is time needed

Comment: @MarkBaker there is to ways, we can code everyday, and do more or less same work, same tasks, or you can do programming, and try to learn something new how to do, this one, i really don't have idea, i think i know what is needed to do, but i really don't know how, honestly, i don't know

Comment: Give me 5 minutes to write a skeleton for you.... you'll learn something from it, not to do it if you want any kind of performance

Comment: @MarkBaker ok, thank you so much, any kind of help is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have to put yourself through this pain, at least it's a fairly simple query.

Something like

```
$a = fopen('a.csv', 'r');
$b = fopen('b.csv', 'r');
$c = fopen('c.csv', 'r');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

while (($dataA = fgetcsv($a, 1024, ",")) !== false) {
    if ($dataA[0] == 'some_text') {
        $bCount = 0;
        rewind($b);
        while (($dataB = fgetcsv($b, 1024, ",")) !== false) {
            if ($dataB[0] == $dataA[3]) {
                $bCount = 0;
                $cCount = 0;
                rewind($c);
                while (($dataC = fgetcsv($c, 1024, ",")) !== false) {
                    if ($dataC[0] == $dataA[4]) {
                        fputcsv($output, [$dataA[1], $dataA[2], $dataB[1], $dataC[1]]);
                        ++$cCount;
                    }
                }
                if ($cCount == 0) {
                    fputcsv($output, [$dataA[1], $dataA[2], $dataB[1], null]);
                }
                ++$bCount;
            }
        }
        if ($bCount == 0) {
            $cCount = 0;
            rewind($c);
            while (($dataC = fgetcsv($c, 1024, ",")) !== false) {
                if ($dataC[0] == $dataA[4]) {
                    fputcsv($output, [$dataA[1], $dataA[2], null, $dataC[1]]);
                    ++$cCount;
                }
            }
            if ($cCount == 0) {
                fputcsv($output, [$dataA[1], $dataA[2], null, null]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

would be pretty close to what you want.

Modify your row IDs to suit your query. If you want to "name" your cells in each row to make the code more "readable", then that's an overhead, and this will take long enough to run anyway

---

**EDIT**

Logically, it loops through file a, testing each row in turn to see if it matches your where criteria, ignoring any row that doesn't match and moving on to the next. If it does find a match, then it does a lookup against file b, looping through until it finds any match (the if test there). If it does find a match against b, it then loops against c. If an match is found against c (an if test again), then it displays the result (writing the value from your select as a comma separated list from all 3 files). If no match is found in c, then it displays the values from a and b with a null instead of any value from c. If no matching value is found in b, then it loops against c looking for a match, and displays any matches from a and c with a null for the select value from b. If no matching values re found in either b or c, then it displays the a values with nulls for the b and c cells. The rewinds for b and c loops ensure that the loops will always check from the beginning of the file.

---

There's no easy way to search a csv other than iterating through the entire file. You could loop through each file a single time caching results against an index to make subsequent loops easier if you had unlimited memory, but PHP isn't the right language for memory-intensive tasks.

Of course, if had unlimited memory and could load the entirety of each file into 3 arrays, then you could use a query tool like LINQ to handle the query

Comment: At first, thank you so much on help,i really appreciate your time and effort , it really means to me, honestly, i don't even now what does this do, i have add my csv files on part 'some text' i entered what i want , and it gives back one row with values, but i don't know why it gives back that values, so i will look what can i do, this is not doing what i want, but probably is good start point, i will accept your answer. I must say, i would like to have just a little bit of your logic and thinking, so i can write algorithms as u do , thank you Mark so much, you are great!